# equivalent metric space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space where $d$ is unbounded, that is,
$$\sup\{d(x; y) : x, y\in X\} = \infty$$ 
Define a bounded metric $p$ on $X$ such that:

$(i).$ $f : (X, d) \rightarrow (X, p)$, $f(x) = x$ , is a homeomorphism.

$(ii).$ $p$ and $d$ are not equivalent.

Comment: In (ii) do you really mean *not* equivalent? Your title suggests that you don’t.

Comment: The fact that there is a homeomorphism (in my book) means exactly that they're equivalent metrics. Or do you have another definition of equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are asking about (lack of) [strong equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics#Strong_equivalence) of metrics? Two metrics $d_1,d_2$ on a set $X$ are called *strongly equivalent* if $\alpha,\beta>0$ exist such that $$\alpha d_1(x,y) \leq d_2(x,y) \leq \beta d_1(x,y)$$ for all $x,y\in X$.

Let $X=(-1,1)$ and let $d_1$ be the standard metric on the interval $X$. For $x,y\in X$ let $d_2(x,y)=|\tan(x)-\tan(y)|$. Then $\operatorname{id}_X\colon (X,d_1)\to (X,d_2)$ is a homeomorphism, $d_1$ is bounded, $d_2$ is unbounded, and the two metrics on $X$ are not strongly equivalent. (Moreover, $(X,d_2)$ is a complete metric space, while $(X,d_1)$ is not complete.)

Answer (score 1):

Using the idea of strong equivalence Michal gives above...given $d$ we can define such a $p$ by

$$p(x,y) = \frac{d(x,y)}{1 + d(x,y)}$$

Comment: can you explain why $p$ and $d$ would not be strongly equivalent in this case?